# Arcade expression for FIND using multiple values - getting error for wrong number of arguments

Tags: expression, arcade, find

This is a selection of my data.

CLVM71-01,
CLVM71-02,
CLVM72-01,
CLVM72-02,
CLVX71-01,
CLVX72-01,
CLVX73-01,
CLVX73-02,
CLVN73-01,
CLVN72-01,
CLVA71-01,
CLVA72-01,
CLVA73-01,
CLVA74-01,
CLVM74-01,
CLVN74-01,
CLVM74-02

I would like to symbolise based on the text codes in the middle of the asset ID.

Anything with a "71" ie: "VN71", "VM71", "VX71", "VA71" is known as "C2"

Anything with a "72" ie: "VN72", "VM72", "VX72", "VA72" is known as "C1"

Anything with a "73" ie: "VN73", "VM73", "VX73", "VA73" is known as "AIR"

Anything with a "74" ie: "VN74", "VM74", "VX74", "VA74" is known as "DSL"

How would the arcade expression look when trying to achieve this?

I had previously phrased the same question, however when using the provided expression below, I get multiple lines of symbolism (over 500).
Using the short data list above, i should only get 4 different lines/classes of symbolism.
Below is a snapshot showing the multiple lines of symbolism when using the provided answer.

[image: Using the answer provided below i still get too many results]

Comment: Is this expression for [Calculate Field (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm)?  If so, are you open to using Python?  Arcade does not support regular expressions which makes something like this rather convoluted.

Comment: Hi, it's for arcgis pro symbology. so think im stuck with arcade. Does this mean, i have to have a line of code for each argument. That what i was starting to write out but thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the When() function.

Looking at your values closer makes it seem like this might work as well:

```
var txt = $feature.ASSETID
var C2 = "71"
var C1 = "72"
var AIR = "73"
var DSL = "74"
var default = ""
var output = When(
    Find(C2, txt, 1) > -1, "C2",
    Find(C1, txt, 1) > -1, "C1",
    Find(AIR, txt, 1) > -1, "AIR",
    Find(DSL, txt, 1) > -1, "DSL",
    default
)
return output
```

Comment: @bixb0012 - is the swap out using the Includes() function working better for you?

Comment: @Invercargill, which of these options looks like a better fit for you?

Comment: Hi thanks for that, the 1st one is a better fit. There is way more combos in the data than i realised. I would also like to add a : if none of the above then "x" (or something) as i'm getting a lot of lines of symbolism for all the ones not specified (over 100).

Comment: Appears to be typo in `Find` code, specifically using `cty` without defining it.  Changing `cty` to `txt` the code works.  Both approaches work, after updating second code block, given the limited information the OP has provided.  That said, the `Includes` approach depends on exact matches which would fail if an Asset ID was like "VM76-Foo", and the `Find` approach would potentially succeed when maybe it shouldn't like for an Asset ID of "BC76-".

Comment: @bixb0012 - You are correct. I moved code that I was testing on data I had at the ready and forgot to change the variable name back to 'txt'. Fixed it.

Comment: @Invercargill - if that answers your question I would truly appreciate if you could mark it as an official answer.

Comment: Hi, Im still getting too many results. see image below. hmmmm cant seem to add a sceen shot.

Comment: i have added the screen shot to the original post above, you can see that im getting multiple results for "VM75" which is the thing im trying to avoid.

Comment: hello, i am still stuck and waiting for some help please, i tried to start a new question to help us get to an answer but it got shut down, so now im back here. is this thread still alive or is it dead?

Comment: @Invercargill, one issue is that you changed the field mappings from when you first asked the question so the code samples in original answers won't give desired result.  Regarding all the unmapped values showing up in the legend, just change the default value of the `When` statement.  I submitted a code edit of this answer to make changes that should work.

Comment: Thank you, that last code edit works perfectly.